# What is the @_(get: "edges") notation?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I am relatively new to GraphQL and have seen some notations like  `@_(get: "edges")` in our GraphQL queries. We are using Apollo and PostGraphile. I have tried looking for some documentation on this, however can't seem to find any. Other things I have seen are: 
`@_(get: "edges", flattenDepth: 1, groupBy: "contentType")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your team is using [graphql-lodash](https://github.com/APIs-guru/graphql-lodash), which is an experimental library that allows you to arbitrarily transform GraphQL responses on the client side using functions from [lodash](https://lodash.com).

Comment: Noticed that they have added this over the top in a custom component, not sure how I missed that ‍♂️

Thanks!